# Не могу установить nginx и запустить проект на нем. Windows 11

Tags: javascript, windows, nginx, npm, install

Всем привет! Расскажу кратко: потребовалось перейти с мака на винду, чтобы проверить работоспособность сайта. Все зависимости установил, конфиги настроил, в общем-то сделал все на маке.

Пытаюсь установить nginx(уже часа 3 :) ), получаю такой ответ:

```
bdc1@bdc1 /c/Dev/smartclient-web/web/src/smartclient (50-fixbugs)
$ npm install nginx

up to date, audited 474 packages in 1s

28 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

При проверке `nginx -v`, получаю:

```
$ nginx -v
bash: nginx: command not found
```

Как установить nginx на windows 11?

Comment: Просто скачать nginx для windows и прочитать документацию. Он будет в отдельной папке, там никакого колдовства не требуется. Раскидываешь всё по папкам в конфиге пишешь пути, запускаешь nginx.exe и всё работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [официальной документацией Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html)

[Пакет](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nginx), который вы пытаетесь установить через npm мало чего общего с ней имеет. Плюсом в его readme четко написано:

> ONLY WORKS ON UBUNTU LINUX AT THIS TIME

Comment: спасибо, начал пробовать через cmd - получилось) теперь борюсь с этой ошибкой в логах: "proxy_connect_timeout" directive invalid value in C:\nginx-1.23.3/conf/default.conf:6